# After update Joomla 2.5.24 to 2.5.27 i get JDispatcher: :register: Event handler not recognised. Handler: Array

Tags: joomla-2.5

After updated **3** of my Joomla websites i am receiving this error in frontpage.

```
JDispatcher: :register: Event handler not recognised. Handler: Array
```

All of 3 sites were v2.5 and i now using the latest 2.5.27. I fixed databases from Extension manager. I disabled SEF and errors in error_log are like these:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  function_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /public_html/libraries/joomla/event/dispatcher.php on line 101
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  class_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /public_html/libraries/joomla/event/dispatcher.php on line 107
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /public_html/libraries/joomla/methods.php on line 342
```

My linux box is Debian Wheezy and i am using PHP-CGI 5.4.4-14+deb7u14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad! I installed latest version on Akeeba Admin Tools and problem fixed!

Comment: I had the same issue and temporarily uninstalled Akeeba Admin Tools to work around the issue in the meantime.

Comment: @NeilRobertson You can just update it to the latest version!

Comment: I think the issue for me was more to do with this: https://www.akeebabackup.com/home/news/1607-problems-with-admin-tools-3-2-x.html - I should be able to reinstall v3.1.1 though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla seems to be screwing up a lot of their recent updates. Everything seems to be rushed and it appears this could be a bug.

I would suggest reporting it as an issue on the [Joomla issue tracker](http://issues.joomla.org/).

Comment: Thanks a lot @lodder. Yeah i noticed that they did 3 updates in 3 days so it is being rushed for sure.. But it's so weird that i can't find anything similar in Google while searching only for lasts week results. I am afraid that is my server that cause the problem. My Joomla 3.3 on the other hand is working without errors

Comment: Its a huge community so if it was a Joomla bug, Google would be full of the same question :D

Comment: It might be a bug within the latest update which was released yesterday so I doubt there would be much information on it. Either way, report it on Github so they are aware ;)